# ncurses printw() doesn't print anything into window

Tags: c, ncurses

I am trying to create a window and print some text to it using ncurses but I am just getting a blank screen. I believe that `printw()` is not working because I was able to open a working window with the same functions in the same order in a different program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char string[] = "string";

int main(void)
{
    system("clear");
    int c;
    initscr();
    curs_set(0);
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    cbreak();
    WINDOW *game_window;
    game_window=newwin(40,40,1,1);
    int num=0, highs=0;
    while (TRUE) {
        clear();
        printw("\t%s\n", string);
        printw("\tScore: %d    High Score: %d\n", num, highs);
        sleep(1);
        break;
    }
    endwin();
    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you are printing this (I believe this is your intention) in game_window, use **wprintw** instead of **printw**:

```c
wprintw(game_window, "\t%s\n", string);
wprintw(game_window, "\tScore: %d    High Score: %d\n", num, highs);
```

also, don't forget to that ncurses requires you to **refresh** windows:

```c
refresh(); // main screen
wrefresh(game_window); // game_window window
```

That should help! Here's the whole code so you know where I placed above ;)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char string[] = "string";

int main(void)
{
    system("clear");
    int c;
    initscr();
    curs_set(0);
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    cbreak();
    WINDOW *game_window;
    game_window=newwin(40,40,1,1);
    int num=0, highs=0;
    while (TRUE) {
        clear();
        wprintw(game_window, "\t%s\n", string);
        wprintw(game_window, "\tScore: %d    High Score: %d\n", num, highs);
        refresh();
        wrefresh(game_window);
        sleep(1);
        break;
    }
    endwin();
    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a small addition to this answer: despite of what it looks, the print function family are only updating the data structures representing the windows (or the default stdscr). Thus, the reason why you have to invoke the refresh function family is to actually apply such updates to the drawn windows on the computer screen (or the default stdscr).